# python string (with space) matching

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, string-comparison

while trying to eliminate few strings in the list of strings, I tried to use a simple code similar to:

```
>>> s = ['a b', 'c d', 'e f', 'g h']
>>> for i in s:
...     if i is not 'e f':
...         print(i)
...
a b
c d
e f    # this should not get printed, right?
g h
```

and i am unable to understand the underlying behavior?
can u explain? because the following seems logical and above should also work accordingly

```
>>> if 'a b' is not 'a b':
...     True
... else:
...     False
...
False
>>> s = ['a', 'c', 'e', 'g']
>>> for i in s:
...     if i is not 'e':
...         print(i)
...
a
c
g
```

are spaces to be treated specially? What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is not` is an identity based test; when it works on strings, it's due to interning of strings or the small string cache; it's an implementation detail that should never be relied on.

Don't use `is`/`is not` in general, except for comparisons to `None`, until you really understand what it's doing. You want `!=` here, which [tests *value*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons) (do the two objects represent the same logical information?), not `is not`, which [tests *identity*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not) (are both things referring to the exact same object?).

If you wanted to force this to work, you could do something terrible, like explicitly `intern`ing all the strings involved, but that doesn't save any work (the work is spent interning them), and it's generally frowned upon.